# Forçar um header 200 no Ajax enquanto a função PHP fica em sleep

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Estou criando uma função de chat, porém, o servidor ficar aguardando uma interação do BD durante um período de 10 segundos.

O problema é que, enquanto a conexão Ajax fica aberta esperando uma resposta dentro dos 10 segundos, o navegador não aceita trocar de página.

Notei que o Facebook envia um header 200 e mantém a conexão aberta, isso faz com que esse tipo de problema não aconteça.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como posso forçar uma resposta header?

Comment: Seu código tem alguma linha como essa? `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");`

Comment: Sim, mas não adianta, pois ele só retorna o header quando todo o script foi executado.

Comment: E assim você está travando uma thread preciosa do servidor web por 10 segundos, o que significa que com poucas pessoas no chat seu servidor web vai travar inteiro. Você não deve segurar script PHP rodando por nada. PHP tem que terminar o script o mais rápido possível. Se quer fazer long polling, melhor escolher outra tecnologia. Quanto ao seu chat, procure estudar websockets, ou use o AJAX da forma que todo mundo usa: requisição e resposta rápida. Se tiver algum timer, que seja no lado do JS.

Comment: Qual tecnologia acredita que o facebook esta utilizando? Eu acompanhei o relatório e ele esta fazendo um long polling de 50 segundos... a diferença é que ele consegue dar uma resposta para o HTTP antes de concluir o curso dos 50 segundos. Após esse prazo ele fecha e abre uma nova chamada.

Comment: @RodrigoCoelho o PHP do FB é gerenciado por um engine especial, e além disso nao é só o parser que conta, é o modo como você configura a estrutura. Não tem nada a ver com o Apache + PHP que se instala por padrão nas máquinas "por aí". Só pra você ter uma idéia, veja uma das tecnologias: https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150415177928920 - E mesmo assim eu ainda acho que você resolveria bem com WebSockets ou AJAX "normal".

Comment: Certo.. para que eu não fique girando em torno do mesmo problema, o que sugere? Um exemplo pode ser as ações do stackoverflow. Sem eu sair da tela, ele já exibe que tive respostas. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: O Stack Overflow usa websockets para isso.

Comment: @RodrigoCoelho o SO usa WebSockets. Mas para você não ter que aprender uma tecnologia nova, pode usar AJAX retornando um JSON com as conversas novas a cada N segundos (requisições demais são ruins também, mas ainda é melhor que long polling neste caso. Quando o server "apertar", migre pra websockets).

Comment: Ok, vlw pelas dicas.

Comment: De qualquer forma, agora que você entendeu a idéia, segue um caminho pro que foi perguntado originalmente: Depois do header você pode mandar alguma sequencia de bytes inicial, e ir usando isso aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.flush.php só que lembre-se dos riscos envolvidos. Os threads do webserver tem quantidade limitada de atendimentos simultâneos.

Answer (score 3):

O chat do facebook utiliza um framework web assíncrono feito em Python, o [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).
O conceito de servidores assícronos é diferente, já que todo o processo é feito por conexões de stream. Esse conceito é utilizado também em servidores Node.js (já pela natureza assícrona do javascript).

Se seu objetivo é fazer um chat, é possível utilizar o port do [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) para o PHP [Elephant.io](http://elephant.io/). Não utilizei o port para PHP, somente o original (do Node.js), mas ele é realmente bom no que faz! ;)